# How do delete consecutive duplicate rows from pandas dataframe while also updating column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data structure:

```
     |a       |b     |start_time  |end_time
0    |aaba    |d     |11:26       | 11:27
1    |aba     |c     |11:27       | 11:32
2    |aba     |c     |11:32       | 11:34
3    |cab     |ab    |11:34       | 11:35
4    |aba     |c     |11:35       | 11:40
```

I want to merge the duplicate consecutive rows on columns `a` and `b` and then I want to update the `start_time` and `end_time` of the new row to be the earlier of the two and the later of the two, respectively.

Because the entries are consecutive, this means keep the `start_time` of the first and `end_time` of second. Usually there are two duplicates one after another.

So in the case above, I want to merge rows `1` and `2` and end up with:

```
     |a    |b    |start_time  |end_time
0    |aaba    |d     |11:26       | 11:27
1    |aba     |c     |11:27       | 11:34
2    |cab     |ab    |11:34       | 11:35
3    |aba     |c     |11:35       | 11:40
```

I tried using `loc` and on the first run to update the `end_time` column, and on second remove the duplicates, but it seems wasteful to run twice `loc`:

```py
df.loc[(df['a']+df['b']) == (df['a']+df['b']).shift(-1), 'end_time'] = df['end_time'].shift(-1)

df = df.loc[(df['a']+df['b']) != (df['a']+df['b']).shift(-1)]
```

Is there a way to remove the duplicates and update the `end_time` value only through one iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Doing `groupby` on `a`, `b` and groupID on consecutive `b` with `as_index=False`. `agg` min for `start_time` and max for `end_time` per each group

```
df.groupby(['a','b', df.b.ne(df.b.shift()).cumsum()], as_index=False).agg({'start_time': 'min', 'end_time': 'max'})

Out[1649]:
      a   b start_time end_time
0  aaba   d      11:26    11:27
1   aba   c      11:27    11:34
2   aba   c      11:35    11:40
3   cab  ab      11:34    11:35
```